# Sorting HashMap<?,?> by key

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

hello
I need to implement a method that receives a HashMap and sorts (mergeSort) it's values by key **(without using TreeMap, SortedMap or Collections.Sort or use any sort solutions from JAVA Packages)**.
my problem is dealing with the wildcard Types...
this is my implementation (that returns compilation errors because of wildcards use)

```
public HashMap<?, ?> mergeSort(HashMap<?, ?> map) {
        if (map.size() < 1) {
            return map;
        }
        // rounds downwards
        int middle = map.size() / 2;
        int location = 0;

        HashMap<?,?> mapLeft = new HashMap<?, ?>();
        HashMap<?,?> mapRight = new HashMap<?, ?>();
        // splitting map
        for (Iterator<?> keyIter = map.keySet().iterator(); keyIter.hasNext();) {
            if (location < middle) {
                mapLeft.put(keyIter, map.get(keyIter));
            } else {
                mapRight.put(keyIter, map.get(keyIter));
            }
            location++;
        }
        // recursive call
        mapLeft = mergeSort(mapLeft);
        mapRight = mergeSort(mapRight);
        return merge(mapLeft, mapRight);
    }

    public HashMap<?, ?> merge(HashMap<?, ?> mapLeft, HashMap<?, ?> mapRight) {
        HashMap<?, ?> result = new HashMap<?, ?>();
        Iterator<?> keyLeftIter = mapLeft.keySet().iterator();
        Iterator<?> keyRightIter = mapRight.keySet().iterator();
        String keyLeft;
        String keyRight;
        while (keyLeftIter.hasNext()) {
            keyLeft = keyLeftIter.next();
            while (keyRightIter.hasNext()) {
                keyRight = keyRightIter.next();

                if (keyLeft.compareTo(keyRight) < 0) {
                    result.put(keyLeft, mapLeft.get(keyLeft));
                    keyLeft = keyLeftIter.next();
                } else {
                    result.put(keyRight, mapRight.get(keyRight));
                    keyRight = keyRightIter.next();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I appreciate your help!

Comment: What are your compilation errors ?

Comment: Read up on how to use Generics in HashMap's code here http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/HashMap.java.html You cannot use ? and ? everywhere making it generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other commenters I would suggest reading up on the subject of generics in Java. What you did in merge is using wildcards on the result HashMap

```
HashMap<?, ?> result = new HashMap<?, ?>();
```

When you put wildcards on it, you are basically saying "I will only be reading from this". Later on you trying to push something in

```
result.put(keyLeft, mapLeft.get(keyLeft));
```

The compiler will say "Hey, you just told me you would only read and now you want to put something in... FAIL

Then it generates your compile time errors.

**Solution**

Don't put wildcards on collections you will modify.

Comment: this is a really good explanation - thank you. In addition I also clarified the question and added that I cannot use TreeMap, SortedMap or Collections.Sort or use any sort solutions from JAVA Packages.

Answer (score 4):

If all you have to do is meet a method contract, you can do this.

```
public HashMap<?, ?> mergeSort(HashMap<?, ?> map) {
    return new LinkedHashMap(new TreeMap(map));
}
```

This will sort the keys and return a subclass of HashMap. The design of this method is broken, but sometimes you can't change things.

---

If you are sorting a map, you should be using a SortedMap like TreeMap.  hashmap doesn't retain an order so using it for a merge sort is not possible.  Using a merge sort for a TreeMap is redundant.

You cannot assume that `?` is a Comparable.  You can write something like.

```
public static <K extends Comparable<K>, V> SortedMap<K,V> sort(Map<K,V> map) {
    return new TreeMap<K, V>(map);
}
```

As you can see this is shorter and simpler than your approach. Is this homework? Do you reall need to use a merge sort?

The problem you have is that you cannot return a HashMap as it doesn't keep the order, adn you cannot return a TreeMap because it will sort the keys for you making anything else you redundant.  For this task you can only return a LinkedHashMap as it does retain order, without doing the sorting for you.

---

here is an example using LinkedHashMap.  Note it doesn't create copies of Maps as it goes, it creates a single array and merge sorts portions of it until its completely sorted.

Note: I use TreeMap as a SortedMap to show its sorted correctly. ;)

```
public static void main(String... args) throws IOException {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        map.put((int)(Math.random()*1000), i);
    System.out.println("Unsorted "+map);
    System.out.println("Sorted "+sort(map));
    final String sortedToString = sort(map).toString();
    final String treeMapToString = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(map).toString();
    if (!sortedToString.equals(treeMapToString))
        System.out.println(sortedToString+" != \n"+treeMapToString);
}

public static <K extends Comparable<K>, V> Map<K, V> sort(Map<K, V> map) {
    return mergeSort(map);
}

// a very bad design idea, but needed for compatibility.
public static <K extends Comparable<K>, V> HashMap<K, V> mergeSort(Map<K, V> map) {
    Map.Entry<K, V>[] entries = map.entrySet().toArray(new Map.Entry[map.size()]);
    mergeSort0(entries, 0, entries.length);
    HashMap<K, V> ret = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entries)
        ret.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    return ret;
}

private static <K extends Comparable<K>, V> void mergeSort0(Map.Entry<K, V>[] entries, int start, int end) {
    int len = end - start;
    if (len < 2) return;
    int mid = (end + start) >>> 1;
    mergeSort0(entries, start, mid);
    mergeSort0(entries, mid, end);
    // merge [start, mid) and [mid, end)  to [start, end)
    for(int p = start, l=start, r=mid; p < end && l < r && r < end; p++) {
        int cmp = entries[l].getKey().compareTo(entries[r].getKey());
        if (cmp <=  0) {
            l++;
            // the entry is in the right place already
        } else if (p != r) {
            // we need to insert the entry from the right
            Map.Entry<K,V> e= entries[r];
            // shift up.
            System.arraycopy(entries, p, entries, p+1, r - p);
            l++;
            // move down.
            entries[p] = e;
            r++;
        }
    }
}
```

prints

```
Unsorted {687=13, 551=0, 2=15, 984=3, 608=6, 714=16, 744=1, 272=5, 854=9, 96=2, 918=18, 829=8, 109=14, 346=7, 522=4, 626=19, 495=12, 695=17, 247=11, 725=10}
Sorted {2=15, 96=2, 109=14, 247=11, 272=5, 346=7, 495=12, 522=4, 551=0, 608=6, 626=19, 687=13, 695=17, 714=16, 725=10, 744=1, 829=8, 854=9, 918=18, 984=3}
```

Comment: this is a good answer! but I cannot change the signature of my method: public HashMap<?, ?> mergeSort(HashMap<?, ?> map). also I cannot use TreeMap or SortedMap (I've added these changes) - sorry for not being clear enough.

Comment: See my edit. As I said HashMap is not ordered or sorted. However LinkedHashMap extends HashMap so you can return it as if it were a plain HashMap.  Certainly whoever insisted it be a concrete class at all, esp one which cannot be sorted, should have something equally unpleasant happen to them. :-P

Comment: +1 for catching the next compiler complaint, the fact that keys might not implement Comparable. `?` for the key complicated the problem as it is not clear if the solution has to be generic.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you always using `?`. Give the kids a name like `Key` or `Value`.

Edit: You should work through this tutorial fist: [Lesson: Generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html)

Answer (score -2):

Here is a method that sorts a Map by its keys. It makes use of the `Collections.sort(List, Comparator)` method.

```
static Map sortByKey(Map map) {
     List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
     Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
          public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
               return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getKey())
              .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getKey());
          }
     });

    Map result = new LinkedHashMap();
    for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
        result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: thanks! since lots of users said I sould use SortedMap, I clarified my question and added that I cannot use TreeMap, SortedMap or Collections.Sort or use any sort solutions from JAVA Packages.