# Java - Returning Collections

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Problem: 
Write a method called personIndex() where you pass in an ArrayList of person objects. Place each person object with its corresponding id number in HashMap. Return a collection of the person objects in order.

Could someone explain / show how I would do this?

This is my code:

```
public Collection<person> personIndex(ArrayList<Person> parameterArr)
{
    HashMap<String, Person> answerMap = new HashMap<String, Person>();

    for (Person p: parameterArr)
    {
        answerMap.put(p.getID(), p)
    }
     return answerMap.values();
}
```

Question: Is my code correct? Will it return a collection?

I want to know if this is a syntactically correct way to return a collection, and also how would you write this method?

PROBLEM:
when you write the method nothing is being returned but the compiler says everything is syntactically correct

Thank you!

Comment: You write some code.. Run into trouble.. and we will be happy to help.. :)

Comment: public Collection<person> personIndex(ArrayList<Person> parameterArr)
{
 HashMap<String, Person> answerMap = new HashMap<String, Person>();

 for (Person p: parameterArr)
 {
  answerMap.put(p.getID(), p)
 }
     return answerMap.values();
}

Comment: So whats your problem/question with the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting HashMap<?,?> by key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5855783/sorting-hashmap-by-key)

Comment: Did you run your code and test it? What is the expected result and what are you getting?

Comment: I want to know if this is a syntactically correct way to return a collection, and also how would you write this method?

Comment: The Java compiler `javac`, or your favorite IDE, will tell you right away if your code is syntactically correct. (Hint: it's not, why is `person` with a lowercase `p` in `Collection<person>` ?)

Comment: My bad I meant to make that capitalized, but other than that does the code work?

Comment: this question was on an old exam and I got points docked off for it being a wrong way to write the method

Comment: So just wanting to clarify

Comment: @SophieGele - *Return a collection of the person objects in order.* . You need a `LinkedHashMap`

Comment: @SophieGele - And you can simply return the same `parameterArr`. :P

Comment: @VinodMadyalkar oh hello, LinkedHashMap hasn't been taught yet. So what would be the simplest way to do it?

Comment: @SophieGele - Replace `HashMap<String, Person> answerMap = new HashMap<String, Person>();` with `Map<String, Person> answerMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, Person>();` and tadaaaa. Your ids will be stored in the order they are added :)

Comment: @SophieGele - BTW why do even need a Map?. You are not doing anything with it

Comment: when you write the method nothing is being returned but the compiler says everything is syntactically correct

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have any problem in the method you have shown other than not capitalizing "person" in your method return type to represent the `Person` class.

After the `enhanced-for` loop is finished you have a result of a hashmap with the keys being the person IDs of type `String` and the values being the `Person` objects.  If you want to return the hashmap with its keys in order (1... 2... 3... 4), you can see this question [how to sort Map values by key in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/922528/how-to-sort-map-values-by-key-in-java). Since `String` already implements the `Comparable` interface various methods in the question I linked will have a pre-defined sorting method (from the `String` class) to sort the strings.

After sorting the hashmap you can get the values as a collection and return that, since now it will be sorted depending on the IDs.

In the future please show your attempt at ordering the keys in the hashmap.